# Instrumentation shows even after deleting application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

Even after deleting the application, the instrumentation tests seem to show when I try:

> adb shell pm list instrumentation

I even tried restarting my phone.

How do I manually delete the instrumentation tests?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Let me know if you remember how :)

Answer (score 2):

From gradle you can uninstall your app and your the instrumentation tests with:

```
./gradlew uninstallAll
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with selendroid.

I uninstalled the selendroid apk over the UI, but the following command still showed me instrumentations: `adb shell pm list instrumentation`:
`instrumentation:ch.post.it.nemo.marlin.selendroid/io.selendroid.server.ServerInstrumentation (target=org.test.testapp)
instrumentation:ch.post.it.nemo.marlin.selendroid/io.selendroid.server.LightweightInstrumentation (target=org.test.testapp)`

Then I checked with the package manager on the shell `adb shell pm list packages | grep selendroid`:
`package:ch.post.it.nemo.marlin.selendroid`

After uninstalling the package selendroid over the shell: `adb shell pm uninstall ch.post.it.nemo.marlin.selendroid`the instrumentation disappeared too.

Answer (score 0):

pm uninstall the package name of your instrumentation application.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `adb shell pm uninstall`, the argument is the target package name. In case of your app it will be something like this `com.my.app`, but the instrumentation tests are considered a separate package. By default it should be `<your package name>.test` (e.g. `com.my.app.test`).

So you simply do:

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.my.app.test
```

and you should be good.